# Getting the math right for a Hidden Markov Model in Java

Tags: java, statistics

In an effort to learn and use hidden markov models, I am writing my own code to implement them. I am using this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) to help with my work. I do not wish to resort to pre-written libraries, because I have found I can achieve a better understanding if I write it myself. And no, this isn't a school assignment! :)

Unfortunately, my highest level of education consists of high school computer science and statistics. I have no background in Machine Learning besides the casual poking around with ANN libraries and TensorFlow. I am therefore having a bit of trouble translating mathematical equations into code. Specifically, I'm worried my implementations of the alpha and beta functions aren't functionally correct. If anyone can assist in describing where I messed up and how to correct my mistakes to have a functioning HMM implementation, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Here are my class-wide globals:

```
public int n; //number of states
public int t; //number of observations
public int time; //iteration holder
public double[][] emitprob; //Emission parameter
public double[][] stprob; //State transition parameter
public ArrayList<String> states, observations, x, y;
```

My constructor:

```
public Model(ArrayList<String> sts, ArrayList<String> obs)
{

    //the most important algorithm we need right now is 
    //unsupervised learning through BM. Supervised is 
    //pretty easy.

    //need hashtable of count objects... Aya... 

    //perhaps a learner...?
    states = sts;
    observations = obs;
    n = states.size();
    t = observations.size();

    x = new ArrayList();
    y = new ArrayList();

    time = 0;

    stprob = new double[n][n];

    emitprob = new double[n][t];

    stprob = newDistro(n,n);
    emitprob = newDistro(n,t);

}
```

The newDistro method is for creating a new, uniform, normal distribution:

```
public double[][] newDistro(int x, int y)
{
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    double[][] returnme = new double[x][y];
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            returnme[i][j] = Math.abs(r.nextInt());
            sum += returnme[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            returnme[i][j] /= sum;
        }
    }

    return returnme;
}
```

My viterbi algorithm implementation:

```
public ArrayList<String> viterbi(ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    //K means states
    //T means observations
    //T arrays should be constructed as K * T (N * T)
    ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList();
    String firstObservation = obs.get(0);
    int firstObsIndex = observations.indexOf(firstObservation);
    double[] pi = new double[n]; //initial probs of first obs for each st
    int ts = obs.size();
    double[][] t1 = new double[n][ts];
    double[][] t2 = new double[n][ts];
    int[] y = new int[obs.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < obs.size(); i++)
    {
        y[i] = observations.indexOf(obs.get(i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pi[i] = emitprob[i][firstObsIndex];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        t1[i][0] = pi[i] * emitprob[i][y[0]];
        t2[i][0] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < ts; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            double maxValue = 0;
            int maxIndex = 0;
            //first we compute the max value
            for(int q = 0; q < n; q++)
            {
                double value = t1[q][i-1] * stprob[q][j];
                if(value > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = value; //the max
                    maxIndex = q; //the argmax
                }
            }
            t1[j][i] = emitprob[j][y[i]] * maxValue;
            t2[j][i] = maxIndex;
        }
    }
    int[] z = new int[ts];

    int maxIndex = 0;
    double maxValue = 0.0d;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        double myValue =  t1[k][ts-1];
        if(myValue > maxValue)
        {
            myValue = maxValue;
            maxIndex = k;
        }
    }
    path.add(states.get(maxIndex));

    for(int i = ts-1; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        z[i-1] = (int)t2[z[i]][i];
        path.add(states.get(z[i-1]));
    }
    System.out.println(path.size());
    for(String s: path)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    return path;
}
```

My forward algorithm, which takes place of the alpha function as described later:

```
public double forward(ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    double result = 0;
    int length = obs.size()-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result += alpha(i, length, obs);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The remaining functions are for implementing the Baum-Welch Algorithm.

The alpha function is what I'm afraid I'm doing wrong of the most on here. I had trouble understanding which "direction" it needs to iterate over the sequence - Do I start from the last element (size-1) or the first (at index zero) ?

```
public double alpha(int j, int t, ArrayList<String> obs)
{

    double sum = 0;

    if(t == 0)
    {
        return stprob[0][j];
    }

    else
    {
        String lastObs = obs.get(t);
        int obsIndex = observations.indexOf(lastObs);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += alpha(i, t-1, obs) * stprob[i][j] * emitprob[j][obsIndex];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I'm having similar "correctness" issues with my beta function:

```
public double beta(int i, int t, ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    double result = 0;

    int obsSize = obs.size()-1;

    if(t == obsSize)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        String lastObs = obs.get(t+1);
        int obsIndex = observations.indexOf(lastObs);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            result += beta(j, t+1, obs) * stprob[i][j] * emitprob[j][obsIndex];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm more confident in my gamma function; However, since it explicitly requires use of alpha and beta, obviously I'm worried it'll be "off" somehow.

```
public double gamma(int i, int t, ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    double top = alpha(i, t, obs) * beta(i, t, obs);
    double bottom = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        bottom += alpha(j, t, obs) * beta(j, t, obs);
    }
    return top / bottom;
}
```

Same for my "squiggle" function - I do apologize for naming; Not sure of the actual name for the symbol.

```
public double squiggle(int i, int j, int t, ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    String lastObs = obs.get(t+1);
    int obsIndex = observations.indexOf(lastObs);
    double top = alpha(i, t, obs) * stprob[i][j] * beta(j, t+1, obs) * emitprob[j][obsIndex];
    double bottom = 0;
    double innerSum = 0;
    double outterSum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            innerSum += alpha(i, t, obs) * stprob[i][j] * beta(j, t+1, obs) * emitprob[j][obsIndex];
        }
        outterSum += innerSum;
    }

    return top / bottom;
}
```

Lastly, to update my state transition and emission probability arrays, I have implemented these functions as aStar and bStar.

```
public double aStar(int i, int j, ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    double squiggleSum = 0;
    double gammaSum = 0; 
    int T = obs.size()-1;
    for(int t = 0; t < T; t++)
    {
        squiggleSum += squiggle(i, j, t, obs);
        gammaSum += gamma(i, t, obs);
    }
    return squiggleSum / gammaSum;
}

public double bStar(int i, String v, ArrayList<String> obs)
{
    double top = 0;
    double bottom = 0;

    for(int t = 0; t < obs.size()-1; t++)
    {
        if(obs.get(t).equals(v))
        {
            top += gamma(i, t, obs);
        }
        bottom += gamma(i, t, obs);
    }


    return top / bottom;
}
```

In my understanding, since the b* function includes a piecewise function that returns either 1 or 0, I think implementing it in an "if" statement and only adding the result if the string is equal to the observation history is the same as what is described, since the function would render the call to gamma 0, thus saving a little computation time. Is this correct?

In summation, I want to get my math right, to ensure a successful (albeit simple) HMM implementation. As for the Baum-Welch algorithm, I am having trouble understanding how to implment the complete function - would it be as simple as running aStar over all states (as an n * n FOR loop) and bStar for all observations, inside a loop with a convergence function? Also, what would be a best-practice function for checking for convergence without overfitting?

Please let me know of everything I need to do in order to get this right.

Thank you heavily for any help you can give me!

Comment: Lots of great work here. Unfortunately there is no simple answer. My advice as to how to make progress from here: (1) Start simple and build up. Start with simple Markov process. First compute forward evolution, then likelihood function, then maximum likelihood estimation of transition matrix. Add on observation model to get HMM. Add on functions of increasing complexity as before. (2) When you get stuck, try to reduce the problem to a very simple case for which you know (one way or another) the correct result, then present that in a question here. Good luck and have fun, it's a great topic.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid underflow, one should use a scaling factor in the forward and backward algorithms. To get the correct result, one uses nested for loops and the steps are forward in the forward method.

The backward method is similar to the forward function.
You invoke them from the method of the Baum-Welch algorithm.